# What day of the year did David buy Har Habayis?

Tags: tanach, king-david, yerushalayim-jerusalem

Does anyone know if there are any sources regarding the date David Hamelech stopped the plague by bringing karbanos in the field of Aravnah HaYevusi? It would seem that this should be considered a significant date.